# Redirect page in Android Studio

Tags: java, android

I have a project in Android Studio with login and register, it works but when I click login it writes only "Login Successful", I'd like to have a redirect page to another class, I've tried with Intent but probably I put it in the wrong place because it didn't work.

This is the class LoginActivity:

```
import android.content.Intent;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.design.widget.Snackbar;
import android.support.design.widget.TextInputLayout;
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.text.Html;
import android.text.Spanned;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.EditText;
import android.widget.TextView;

public class LoginActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    //Declaration EditTexts
    EditText editTextEmail;
    EditText editTextPassword;

    //Declaration TextInputLayout
    TextInputLayout textInputLayoutEmail;
    TextInputLayout textInputLayoutPassword;

    //Declaration Button
    Button buttonLogin;

    //Declaration SqliteHelper
    SqliteHelper sqliteHelper;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_login);
        sqliteHelper = new SqliteHelper(this);
        initCreateAccountTextView();
        initViews();

        //set click event of login button
        buttonLogin.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {

                //Check user input is correct or not
                if (validate()) {

                    //Get values from EditText fields
                    String Email = editTextEmail.getText().toString();
                    String Password = editTextPassword.getText().toString();

                    //Authenticate user
                    User currentUser = sqliteHelper.Authenticate(new User(null, null, Email, Password));

                    //Check Authentication is successful or not
                    if (currentUser != null) {
                        Snackbar.make(buttonLogin, "Successfully Logged in!", Snackbar.LENGTH_LONG).show();


                        //User Logged in Successfully Launch You home screen activity
                       /* Intent intent=new Intent(LoginActivity.this,HomeScreenActivity.class);
                        startActivity(intent);
                        finish();*/
                    } else {

                        //User Logged in Failed
                        Snackbar.make(buttonLogin, "Failed to log in , please try again", Snackbar.LENGTH_LONG).show();

                    }
                }
            }
        });    
    }

    //this method used to set Create account TextView text and click event( maltipal colors
    // for TextView yet not supported in Xml so i have done it programmatically)
    private void initCreateAccountTextView() {
        TextView textViewCreateAccount = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.textViewCreateAccount);
        textViewCreateAccount.setText(fromHtml("<font color='#ffffff'>I don't have account yet. </font><font color='#0c0099'>create one</font>"));
        textViewCreateAccount.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {
                Intent intent = new Intent(LoginActivity.this, RegisterActivity.class);
                startActivity(intent);
            }
        });
    }
    //this method is used to connect XML views to its Objects
    private void initViews() {
        editTextEmail = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.editTextEmail);
        editTextPassword = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.editTextPassword);
        textInputLayoutEmail = (TextInputLayout) findViewById(R.id.textInputLayoutEmail);
        textInputLayoutPassword = (TextInputLayout) findViewById(R.id.textInputLayoutPassword);
        buttonLogin = (Button) findViewById(R.id.buttonLogin);
    }
    //This method is for handling fromHtml method deprecation
    @SuppressWarnings("deprecation")
    public static Spanned fromHtml(String html) {
        Spanned result;
        if (android.os.Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= android.os.Build.VERSION_CODES.N) {
            result = Html.fromHtml(html, Html.FROM_HTML_MODE_LEGACY);
        } else {
            result = Html.fromHtml(html);
        }
        return result;
    }
    //This method is used to validate input given by user
    public boolean validate() {
        boolean valid = false;

        //Get values from EditText fields
        String Email = editTextEmail.getText().toString();
        String Password = editTextPassword.getText().toString();

        //Handling validation for Email field
        if (!android.util.Patterns.EMAIL_ADDRESS.matcher(Email).matches()) {
            valid = false;
            textInputLayoutEmail.setError("Please enter valid email!");
        } else {
            valid = true;
            textInputLayoutEmail.setError(null);
        }
        //Handling validation for Password field
        if (Password.isEmpty()) {
            valid = false;
            textInputLayoutPassword.setError("Please enter valid password!");
        } else {
            if (Password.length() > 5) {
                valid = true;
                textInputLayoutPassword.setError(null);
            } else {
                valid = false;
                textInputLayoutPassword.setError("Password is to short!");
            }
        }
        return valid;
    }    
}
```

I tried to put:

```
Intent intent = new Intent(LoginActivity.this, Nextpage.class);
startActivity(intent);
```

just after:

```
 if (currentUser != null) {
                        Snackbar.make(buttonLogin, "Successfully Logged in!", Snackbar.LENGTH_LONG).show();
```

no problem on building but error in the login page.

Somebody could give me a hint?

This is the log:

```
08/11 17:10:30: Launching app
$ adb install-multiple -r -t C:\Users\ASUS\AndroidStudioProjects\Test\app\build\intermediates\split-apk\debug\slices\slice_0.apk C:\Users\ASUS\AndroidStudioProjects\Test\app\build\intermediates\instant-run-apk\debug\app-debug.apk C:\Users\ASUS\AndroidStudioProjects\Test\app\build\intermediates\split-apk\debug\slices\slice_4.apk C:\Users\ASUS\AndroidStudioProjects\Test\app\build\intermediates\split-apk\debug\slices\slice_9.apk C:\Users\ASUS\AndroidStudioProjects\Test\app\build\intermediates\split-apk\debug\slices\slice_5.apk C:\Users\ASUS\AndroidStudioProjects\Test\app\build\intermediates\split-apk\debug\slices\slice_2.apk C:\Users\ASUS\AndroidStudioProjects\Test\app\build\intermediates\split-apk\debug\slices\slice_3.apk C:\Users\ASUS\AndroidStudioProjects\Test\app\build\intermediates\split-apk\debug\slices\slice_7.apk C:\Users\ASUS\AndroidStudioProjects\Test\app\build\intermediates\split-apk\debug\slices\slice_1.apk C:\Users\ASUS\AndroidStudioProjects\Test\app\build\intermediates\split-apk\debug\slices\slice_6.apk C:\Users\ASUS\AndroidStudioProjects\Test\app\build\intermediates\split-apk\debug\slices\slice_8.apk C:\Users\ASUS\AndroidStudioProjects\Test\app\build\intermediates\split-apk\debug\dep\dependencies.apk 
Split APKs installed in 31 s 932 ms
$ adb shell am start -n "com.example.test/com.example.test.LoginActivity" -a android.intent.action.MAIN -c android.intent.category.LAUNCHER -D
Waiting for application to come online: com.example.test | com.example.test.test
Waiting for application to come online: com.example.test | com.example.test.test
Connecting to com.example.test
Capturing and displaying logcat messages from application. This behavior can be disabled in the "Logcat output" section of the "Debugger" settings page.
W/ActivityThread: Application com.example.test is waiting for the debugger on port 8100...
I/System.out: Sending WAIT chunk
I/art: Debugger is active
I/System.out: Debugger has connected
    waiting for debugger to settle...
I/System.out: waiting for debugger to settle...
I/System.out: waiting for debugger to settle...
I/System.out: waiting for debugger to settle...
I/System.out: waiting for debugger to settle...
Connected to the target VM, address: 'localhost:8600', transport: 'socket'
I/System.out: waiting for debugger to settle...
I/System.out: waiting for debugger to settle...
I/System.out: waiting for debugger to settle...
I/System.out: waiting for debugger to settle...
I/System.out: waiting for debugger to settle...
I/System.out: waiting for debugger to settle...
I/System.out: waiting for debugger to settle...
I/System.out: debugger has settled (1411)
W/art: Failed execv(/system/bin/dex2oat --runtime-arg -classpath --runtime-arg  --debuggable --instruction-set=arm --instruction-set-features=smp,div,-atomic_ldrd_strd --runtime-arg -Xrelocate --boot-image=/system/framework/boot.art --runtime-arg -Xms64m --runtime-arg -Xmx512m --compiler-filter=speed --instruction-set-variant=cortex-a7 --instruction-set-features=default --dex-file=/data/app/com.example.test-1/split_lib_dependencies_apk.apk --oat-file=/data/dalvik-cache/arm/data@app@com.example.test-1@split_lib_dependencies_apk.apk@classes.dex) because non-0 exit status
W/art: Failed execv(/system/bin/dex2oat --runtime-arg -classpath --runtime-arg  --debuggable --instruction-set=arm --instruction-set-features=smp,div,-atomic_ldrd_strd --runtime-arg -Xrelocate --boot-image=/system/framework/boot.art --runtime-arg -Xms64m --runtime-arg -Xmx512m --compiler-filter=speed --instruction-set-variant=cortex-a7 --instruction-set-features=default --dex-file=/data/app/com.example.test-1/split_lib_slice_0_apk.apk --oat-file=/data/dalvik-cache/arm/data@app@com.example.test-1@split_lib_slice_0_apk.apk@classes.dex) because non-0 exit status
W/art: Failed execv(/system/bin/dex2oat --runtime-arg -classpath --runtime-arg  --debuggable --instruction-set=arm --instruction-set-features=smp,div,-atomic_ldrd_strd --runtime-arg -Xrelocate --boot-image=/system/framework/boot.art --runtime-arg -Xms64m --runtime-arg -Xmx512m --compiler-filter=speed --instruction-set-variant=cortex-a7 --instruction-set-features=default --dex-file=/data/app/com.example.test-1/split_lib_slice_2_apk.apk --oat-file=/data/dalvik-cache/arm/data@app@com.example.test-1@split_lib_slice_2_apk.apk@classes.dex) because non-0 exit status
W/art: Failed execv(/system/bin/dex2oat --runtime-arg -classpath --runtime-arg  --debuggable --instruction-set=arm --instruction-set-features=smp,div,-atomic_ldrd_strd --runtime-arg -Xrelocate --boot-image=/system/framework/boot.art --runtime-arg -Xms64m --runtime-arg -Xmx512m --compiler-filter=speed --instruction-set-variant=cortex-a7 --instruction-set-features=default --dex-file=/data/app/com.example.test-1/split_lib_slice_3_apk.apk --oat-file=/data/dalvik-cache/arm/data@app@com.example.test-1@split_lib_slice_3_apk.apk@classes.dex) because non-0 exit status
W/art: Failed execv(/system/bin/dex2oat --runtime-arg -classpath --runtime-arg  --debuggable --instruction-set=arm --instruction-set-features=smp,div,-atomic_ldrd_strd --runtime-arg -Xrelocate --boot-image=/system/framework/boot.art --runtime-arg -Xms64m --runtime-arg -Xmx512m --compiler-filter=speed --instruction-set-variant=cortex-a7 --instruction-set-features=default --dex-file=/data/app/com.example.test-1/split_lib_slice_4_apk.apk --oat-file=/data/dalvik-cache/arm/data@app@com.example.test-1@split_lib_slice_4_apk.apk@classes.dex) because non-0 exit status
W/art: Failed execv(/system/bin/dex2oat --runtime-arg -classpath --runtime-arg  --debuggable --instruction-set=arm --instruction-set-features=smp,div,-atomic_ldrd_strd --runtime-arg -Xrelocate --boot-image=/system/framework/boot.art --runtime-arg -Xms64m --runtime-arg -Xmx512m --compiler-filter=speed --instruction-set-variant=cortex-a7 --instruction-set-features=default --dex-file=/data/app/com.example.test-1/split_lib_slice_5_apk.apk --oat-file=/data/dalvik-cache/arm/data@app@com.example.test-1@split_lib_slice_5_apk.apk@classes.dex) because non-0 exit status
W/art: Failed execv(/system/bin/dex2oat --runtime-arg -classpath --runtime-arg  --debuggable --instruction-set=arm --instruction-set-features=smp,div,-atomic_ldrd_strd --runtime-arg -Xrelocate --boot-image=/system/framework/boot.art --runtime-arg -Xms64m --runtime-arg -Xmx512m --compiler-filter=speed --instruction-set-variant=cortex-a7 --instruction-set-features=default --dex-file=/data/app/com.example.test-1/split_lib_slice_6_apk.apk --oat-file=/data/dalvik-cache/arm/data@app@com.example.test-1@split_lib_slice_6_apk.apk@classes.dex) because non-0 exit status
W/art: Failed execv(/system/bin/dex2oat --runtime-arg -classpath --runtime-arg  --debuggable --instruction-set=arm --instruction-set-features=smp,div,-atomic_ldrd_strd --runtime-arg -Xrelocate --boot-image=/system/framework/boot.art --runtime-arg -Xms64m --runtime-arg -Xmx512m --compiler-filter=speed --instruction-set-variant=cortex-a7 --instruction-set-features=default --dex-file=/data/app/com.example.test-1/split_lib_slice_7_apk.apk --oat-file=/data/dalvik-cache/arm/data@app@com.example.test-1@split_lib_slice_7_apk.apk@classes.dex) because non-0 exit status
W/art: Failed execv(/system/bin/dex2oat --runtime-arg -classpath --runtime-arg  --debuggable --instruction-set=arm --instruction-set-features=smp,div,-atomic_ldrd_strd --runtime-arg -Xrelocate --boot-image=/system/framework/boot.art --runtime-arg -Xms64m --runtime-arg -Xmx512m --compiler-filter=speed --instruction-set-variant=cortex-a7 --instruction-set-features=default --dex-file=/data/app/com.example.test-1/split_lib_slice_8_apk.apk --oat-file=/data/dalvik-cache/arm/data@app@com.example.test-1@split_lib_slice_8_apk.apk@classes.dex) because non-0 exit status
W/art: Failed execv(/system/bin/dex2oat --runtime-arg -classpath --runtime-arg  --debuggable --instruction-set=arm --instruction-set-features=smp,div,-atomic_ldrd_strd --runtime-arg -Xrelocate --boot-image=/system/framework/boot.art --runtime-arg -Xms64m --runtime-arg -Xmx512m --compiler-filter=speed --instruction-set-variant=cortex-a7 --instruction-set-features=default --dex-file=/data/app/com.example.test-1/split_lib_slice_9_apk.apk --oat-file=/data/dalvik-cache/arm/data@app@com.example.test-1@split_lib_slice_9_apk.apk@classes.dex) because non-0 exit status
W/System: ClassLoader referenced unknown path: /data/app/com.example.test-1/lib/arm
I/InstantRun: starting instant run server: is main process
W/ResourceType: Failure getting entry for 0x01080a8c (t=7 e=2700) (error -75)
W/art: Before Android 4.1, method android.graphics.PorterDuffColorFilter android.support.graphics.drawable.VectorDrawableCompat.updateTintFilter(android.graphics.PorterDuffColorFilter, android.content.res.ColorStateList, android.graphics.PorterDuff$Mode) would have incorrectly overridden the package-private method in android.graphics.drawable.Drawable
I/art: Rejecting re-init on previously-failed class java.lang.Class<android.support.v4.view.ViewCompat$OnUnhandledKeyEventListenerWrapper>
    Rejecting re-init on previously-failed class java.lang.Class<android.support.v4.view.ViewCompat$OnUnhandledKeyEventListenerWrapper>
W/ResourceType: Failure getting entry for 0x01080a8c (t=7 e=2700) (error -75)
D/TextView: setTypeface with style : 0
D/TextView: setTypeface with style : 0
D/TextView: setTypeface with style : 0
D/TextView: setTypeface with style : 0
D/TextView: setTypeface with style : 0
    setTypeface with style : 0
D/TextView: setTypeface with style : 0
D/TextView: setTypeface with style : 0
D/TextView: setTypeface with style : 0
D/TextView: setTypeface with style : 0
D/SecWifiDisplayUtil: Metadata value : none
D/ViewRootImpl: #1 mView = com.android.internal.policy.PhoneWindow$DecorView{eadc180 I.E...... R.....ID 0,0-0,0}
D/OpenGLRenderer: Use EGL_SWAP_BEHAVIOR_PRESERVED: false
V/ActivityThread: updateVisibility : ActivityRecord{2e404d6 token=android.os.BinderProxy@f93b57c {com.example.test/com.example.test.LoginActivity}} show : true
D/libEGL: loaded /system/lib/egl/libEGL_mali.so
D/libEGL: loaded /system/lib/egl/libGLESv1_CM_mali.so
D/libEGL: loaded /system/lib/egl/libGLESv2_mali.so
I/Mali: Mali API Version : 401
    Mali REVISION: Linux-r4p0-00rel0  BUILD_DATE: 2016-07-26 20:39:31 
D/libEGL: eglInitialize EGLDisplay = 0x5513a7cc
I/OpenGLRenderer: Initialized EGL, version 1.4
D/ViewRootImpl: MSG_RESIZED_REPORT: ci=Rect(0, 48 - 0, 0) vi=Rect(0, 48 - 0, 0) or=1
I/Timeline: Timeline: Activity_idle id: android.os.BinderProxy@f93b57c time:10259613
```

Comment: That's fine but is there something shown in red when the app crashes?

Comment: I wrote debug too, no i have no errors, only, when i sign up, it shows me an error with "failed login"

Comment: Nothing else is required but just show what is shown in red

Comment: nothing is in red, i have no problem in building, the problem is only running the app. without intent i have always "login successfull", adding the intent "login failed"

Comment: Wait, in the code, you say you go to `HomeScreenActivity.class` with intent. But after that, you wrote that you want to go to `NextPage.class` Please re-read your question if that seems okay.

Comment: ah no I put that in the comment but then I changed the name of the class, in fact I have no red errors on Nextpage. I forgot to cancel the comment